# Bash restricted Shell using rbash

Tags: bash, shell, account-restrictions, restricted-shell

I am using `/bin/rbash` for some users. It's working as expected but there is some hack like when users run `bash` or `dash`, then they got unrestricted shells, so to avoid these commands, I have added below functions in their `.bashrc` files.

```
bash() {
echo "WARNING: NOT ALLOW!!"
}

sh() {
echo "WARNING: NOT ALLOW!!"
}
```

So my question is:

1# can we use functions with multiple names as below

```
func1,func2 () {
 # do stuff
}
```

2# I also tried:

```
case $BASH_COMMAND in # check each command`
        bash|dash|sh) 
        echo "WARNING: NOT ALLOW!!" 
        ;;
esac
```

3# `/bin/rbash -> bash` it's just a soft link of bash, then how does it work as restricted?

Also there is some command to avoid users to execute that like `unset HISTFILE` and `kill -9 $$`
Is there any alternate way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Do not do this. `rbash` should *only* be used within an already secure environment unless you know what you are doing. There are many ways to break out a restricted bash shell that are not easy to predict in advance.**

Functions can easily be overridden simply by doing `command bash` or `command sh`.

As for your questions:

- You can't define multiple functions at the same time directly. You'd have to do something like this:

```
x()  { foo; }
alias f1=x
alias f2=x
```

- `rbash` works because `bash` checks the value of `argv[0]` on launch. If the basename, with leading dashes stripped, is equal to `RESTRICTED_SHELL_NAME` (defaulting to `rbash`, see `config.h`), it runs in restricted mode. This is the same way that it runs in POSIX-compliance mode if invoked as `sh`. You can see this in the following code from `shell.c` in bash 4.2, lines 1132-1147:

```c
/* Return 1 if the shell should be a restricted one based on NAME or the
   value of `restricted'.  Don't actually do anything, just return a
   boolean value. */
int
shell_is_restricted (name)
     char *name;
{
  char *temp;

  if (restricted)
    return 1;
  temp = base_pathname (name);
  if (*temp == '-')
    temp++;
  return (STREQ (temp, RESTRICTED_SHELL_NAME));
}
```

Comment: @ChrisDown i am doing right to avoid bash,sh command or is there any alternate way  ?

Comment: @RahulPatil No, your method is easily circumvented. Use a chroot.