# Restrict standard users to run a command with a specific argument

Tags: security, sudo, options, account-restrictions

I know how to restrict standard users to run a command by removing execute permissions for that command. But it's possible restrict standard users to run a command with a specific option/argument?

For example a standard user should be able to run the following command:

```
ls
```

but not:

```
ls -l
```

I think that this can be possible since there are some commands like `chsh` or `passwd` which a standard user can run them, but he get permission denied when he runs `chsh root` or `passwd -a -S`.

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/ghantoos/lshell

Comment: @RahulPatil Thanks, but I don't see/understand how can be this related to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only way would be to write your own wrapper to the command/utility in question and have it decide what is allowed or not allowed based on the (E)UID of the user who started it. The tools you mention that do this such as `chsh` or `passwd` have this functionality built into their implementation.

**How to write a wrapper for `ls`**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $problematic_uid = 1000; # For example
my $is_problematic = $< == $problematic_uid;
unless(/ -l / ~~ @ARGV or $is_problematic){
    exec qq{/new/path/to/ls }.join '',@ARGV
}else{
    die "Sorry, you are not allowed to use the -l option to ls\n"
}
```

You need to ensure that the path to the original `ls` isn't in your user's `PATH`. Which is why I wrote `/new/path/to/ls`. The problem is, this wrapper requires that your user be able to execute the original `ls` so the user may still circumvent it by calling the original `ls` directly.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Sure. Give me a few minutes to skim through `man sudoers` and post back here. I know that this is possible from a previous reading of the page but I forgot the mechanics of it.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu It seems this won't work for your use case. The `sudoers` page says if you specify command line arguments then this is the only version of the command the user is allowed to run through `sudo`, which is different to what you want. My bad...

Comment: I was thinking about that, also... But, what about *write your own wrapper to the command...*? How can I do this? Sincerely is first time when I hear about something like this.

Comment: @JosephR. you would have to specify all possible combinations of the options. While this looks impossible fo commands like `ls`, `tar` or `ps`, it could work with a subset of options, if they are at least sorted in a wrapper.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu wrapper is a simple executable (usually in a scripted language) that (often) has the same name as the target executable, but precedes it during command lookup (e.g. it is in a directory, that appears in `PATH` earlier than the target). In your case however, this is quite problematic, since you don't want to allow access to the target executable - yet it has to be accessible to the wrapper.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I agree with peterph. See the updated answer, please.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu done. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

Commands like `chsh` and `passwd` are coded specially. They run with extra privileges (they're [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)) root) and contain their own authorization mechanism. Both check which user is invoking them, and allow non-root users only a subset of their functionality.

`chsh` and `passwd` are the exception. Most commands don't care who invokes them.

Forbidding users from running one particular command is pointless: they can do whatever that command does in some other way, such as by supplying their own executable.

You can make a restricted account that is only allowed to run a whitelisted set of commands: with a [restricted shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59393/bash-restricted-shell-using-rbash), or for data-transfer-only accounts, [rssh or scponly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9837/do-you-need-a-shell-for-scp).

If you want to allow a user to run a certain command with elevated privileges (typically via `sudo`), but only for certain combinations of options, then write a wrapper script that checks the options and allow the user to run that wrapper script.

Answer (score 2):

Rahul's answer is relevant to your question, because what you want is a) not a good idea and b) probably only possible by creating a custom shell. Executables like `ls` are separate, stand-alone programs that handle their arguments by themselves - if you'd want to prevent users from using `ls -l`, you would have to write and compile your own custom `ls`. As you can probably imagine, that would not be easy and it would also take a lot of time, because you have to do that for every single command that you want to change.

You could *maybe* try to replace the whole shell (in your case probably `bash`) completely with a different shell that filters the commands of your users. For example, it could try to remove the `-l` from `ls` command lines before actually calling `ls`. This isn't as easy as it sounds though, because shells and also the commands that you can run from a shell usually have a very powerful and complex syntax, and trying to filter that will probably leave holes and break stuff.

> I think that this can be possible since there are some commands like `chsh` or `passwd` which a standard user can run them, but he get permission denied when he runs `chsh root` or `passwd -a -S`.

That's something else entirely, because these programs are written that way. If you'd want to change their behaviour just as you want to change the behaviour of `ls`, you would have to modify their source codes and recompile them.

Comment: It wouldn't be **that** difficult, since **removing** an option is much easier than adding one (usually you just need to comment out a couple of lines of code).

Comment: Still, it sounds like an insanely bad idea to me, just like "hey, let's disable the desktop icons and the command prompt on the Windows workstations of our users, cause you know, that stuff is DANGEROUS". I really dislike that approach.

Comment: Well, restricting access to a narrow set commands definitely makes sense under some circumstances. Restricting use of some options for `ls` and similar sounds like quite a silly idea indeed (the example of `ls` is definitely a bad one). But for some commands it might make sense as well - c.f. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91214/how-to-create-a-user-account-with-specific-permissions